# How to load JS Library in WebView?

Tags: flutter, dart, uiwebview, android-webview, stripe-payments

I want load Javascript library in Flutter webview.

For example I want use Stripe Checkout. This require load `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` when load url webpage.

How I can add this when open webview url?

Comment: are you using flutter_webview package?

Comment: @YauhenSampir That package doesn't exist on pub.dev. Do you mean `webview_flutter` or are you referring to a different source?

Comment: sure, I mean webview_flutter

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to inject that script into an existing webpage?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes I want inject that script into webpage. Or load up script first and then navigate to different page